# PHP Delete a file into a folder

Tags: php, html, directory

I'm trying to delete specific file name into a folder depend of the action of the user and I receive this warning:

**Warning: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking in**

This is the code that have the button that provide the navigation to the deleteRecord.php

```
> <script>                                                  //btn delete
>         $(".btn_delete").click(function(){
>           var id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
>             //alert(id);                                          
>               var x;
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want delete this record?") == true) {
>                //alert ("You pressed OK!");                                                       
>               
>               location.href='deleteRecord.php?filename='+filename;
>                   } else {
>                       //alert ("You pressed Cancel!");
>                       return false;           }
>         });
>     </script>
```

This work very good I put it to show to where come the variable id

And now this is the php page that return the Warning:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename']; //get the filename like "yo.jpg"

$path = "http://www.here I have the exact address to the folder/";

unlink($path . '/' . $filename);
```

and this is the result I will put it again!

******Warning: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking in******

Any suggestions? Any advice? Please sorry about my english, I'm learning!

Comment: You can't unlink a URL.  You unlink the file on the file system.

Comment: `http://yoursite.com/delete.php?file=/etc/passwd` sanitize and validate your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the *server's* path to the file as the argument to `unlink()` rather than the URL, for example:

```
unlink('/var/www/mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg')
```